# Geo nodes: object color

Tags: geometry-nodes

I've been trying to find a way to get the object color in geo nodes, but can't find a way to read or write this property. Can anyone help me out with how this could be done?

Comment: You can write it using a Set Material node but what happens if the current colour is different on each face of your object? How would you know which colour to choose?

Comment: Hey John, it's not the material color - it's the "viewport display" value, if that makes sense? Was hoping I could set it as an attribute, but now I'm not sure it's an attribute, maybe more of a property.

Comment: It's a property of a material. Unfortunately you can't read such material properties in geonodes. Depending on what's your use case, a workaround could be designed: e.g. creating a data object, with triangles each containing one unique material, and an attribute storing the material's color. Probably Python would have to be used to automatically (re-)generate this data object.

Comment: You could use Drivers. Right-click on viewport color, *Copy Full Data Path*, then create a driver in your geometry nodes and paste inside it the data path.

Comment: @Lutzi I think a driver here is not that great solution: it works as long as the material stays the same, but if the material is changed - the driver will point to the old material, while the intent is probably to point to the current material's color. One could ask: how often is a material changed? Well, from my experience more often than viewport display color is changed. Of course an advanced "elevated" driver can be used to get the current material color, though then an autorun script might be used as well - which would allow for a field support.

Comment: Magnuzoid is talking about the viewport color, not the material color. Plus, you can change the color, the driver is linked by data path and not by value. Drivers don't stop working when you change values. I just tested it and it works (*Single Property* -> Data path = "*color.r*" for red channel, and so on)

Comment: Would the driver allow to be used in multiple modifiers (can the driver be relative and not absolute)?

Comment: Each color field that need to be based on this viewport color should have their own driver. You can copy-paster driver (inside *Driver editor*). So a bit of work for each new object but it works.

Comment: @Lutzi Magnuzoid used the term "Viewport display" which is a property of a material.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady I see. No matter which one of these properties, *Drivers* work the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Read display color inside Geometry nodes with *Drivers*

Here is a way of reading the display color.

Let's say you have 2 objects, *A* and *B*, and you want to read the display color of *A* inside geometry nodes of object *B*.

**Get Data Path**

Right click on display color of object *A*, and *Copy Data Path*. Not mandatory but useful (here we are only copying a *String*).

[image: Get data path from display color]

**Create Driver**

Then inside the geometry nodes of object *B*, choose where you want to get the color and right click on it, and *Add Driver*.

[image: Create new driver]

**Red channel**

Then inside the driver editor, select one channel (here the red channel) and reference the display color. Here are the fields you should fill.

[image: Detailed driver setup]

- **Scripted Expression** : basically we will only get the red channel as a `var` variable, and using it directly. But you could add math to it, for example invert the red channel by giving as an Expression `1-var`. *Warning : by default the expression is `var + 1`, which we don't want here.*
- **Expression** : you can just let `var` as is. It's only the name of the variable used just above.
- **Type** : *Single Property*, we are reading one RGB channel of the color, here red
- **ID Type** : *Material*, because the color you are looking for is part of the material of object A. *Keep in mind this driver references the material and not the object !*
- **Material name** : the name of the material of object A
- **Path** : `diffuse_color.r`. If you paste what we copied at the first step, you should get *diffuse_color*. Just add *.r* to it, meaning we are accessing the red-channel only. For green, blue and alpha channels : `diffuse_color.g`, `diffuse_color.b` and `diffuse_color.a`.

And you have successfully linked the red channel

**Green and blue channel (alpha too if you want)**

Then repeat the **Red channel** section for both the green and blue channels, and alpha if needs be.

**Final result**

Then your *Color* node (object B) will be linked to the display color of the object A.

[image: Final result]

Comment: A huge time-saver is to use the "Copy as New Driver" and "Paste Driver" functionality: https://i.imgur.com/4UaNcoP.gif

Comment: Damn ! I now understand why I wasn't able to find the *Copy as New Driver*. Time-saver indeed !